# In R how can I use multiple prepared statements with DBI + RSQLite simultaneously?

Tags: r, rsqlite, r-dbi

Suppose you're trying to do a typical insert-or-update loop with RSQLite. I would expect the following to work:

```
library(DBI)
testdb <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "test.sqlite")
dbExecute(testdb, "CREATE TABLE spray_count (spray TEXT, count INTEGER)")
urs <- dbSendStatement(testdb, "UPDATE spray_count SET count = count + :count WHERE spray = :spray")
irs <- dbSendStatement(testdb, "INSERT INTO spray_count VALUES (:spray, :count)")
for (i in 1:nrow(InsectSprays)) {
  print(paste("update", i))
  dbBind(urs, InsectSprays[i,])
  if (!dbGetRowsAffected(urs)) {
    print(paste("insert", i))
    dbBind(irs, InsectSprays[i,])
  }
}
```

But it does not:

```
[1] "update 1"
Error in rsqlite_bind_rows(res@ptr, params) : 
  external pointer is not valid
In addition: Warning message:
Closing open result set, pending rows
```

Basically it seems that you can have only one prepared statement at a time, and creating a second one somehow invalidates the first. Am I missing something or is this a limitation of DBI and/or RSQLite? I have DBI v0.6-1 and RSQLite v1.1-2.

Comment: This is deliberate, future versions may lift this restriction. Could you please try opening a second connection for the `INSERT` statement?

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick as a workaround.

Comment: @krlmlr can you say anything more about why it's deliberate or when the restriction might be lifted? There are some situations where the workaround does not suffice...

Comment: It simplifies the definition of the interface and the tests we have to implement to check compliance of a DBI backend. Which situations do you have in mind?